# how can I make zig zag border for the bottom card border

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2, and I want to make the bottom border of A card as Zig zag border but I can't, I need a help to do it and thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your html and css what you have tried so far

Comment: @Duannx I have tried many attempts  as I saw in may online links like https://codepen.io/zoerooney/pen/pvOaxR  & https://codepen.io/AndreiDodu/pen/gziqn & https://codepen.io/gilbarbara/pen/pvwmEb but I can't applay it to the bottom border of the ionic card

Comment: I think this https://codepen.io/zoerooney/pen/pvOaxR is easier to apply. Let try it and show your code. I can not help you without your code.